# BigQuery - Cannot re-use lagged records

Tags: google-bigquery

When using `lag(value,offset)`, I don't seem to be able to re-use the output in other functions.

The output of the following code shows that `previous_timestamp_utc` exists, but neither of the functions, casting to `date()` or `datediff()`, return values.

```
    SELECT
      id,
      timestamp_utc,
      DATE(timestamp_utc) AS date_timestamp_utc,
      previous_timestamp_utc,
      DATE(previous_timestamp_utc) AS date_previous_timestamp_utc,
      DATEDIFF(timestamp_utc,previous_timestamp_utc),
    FROM (
      SELECT
        id,
        timestamp_utc,
        LAG(timestamp_utc,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp_utc) AS previous_timestamp_utc,
      FROM (
        SELECT
          SEC_TO_TIMESTAMP (timestamp) AS timestamp_utc,
          id,
          num_characters,
        FROM
          [publicdata:samples.wikipedia] ) )
    ORDER BY
      4 DESC
    LIMIT
      1000
```

Can anyone explain why this is occurring?

**Workaround:** I'm unclear as to why this works, but a spotted workaround is to pre-cast the `lag()` field into a `date()`: replacing

```
LAG(timestamp_utc,1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp_utc)
```

with

```
LAG(date(timestamp_utc),1) OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timestamp_utc)
```

causes the `previous_timestamp_utc` to be used in a `date()` and `datediff()`.  This is not something we should be expected to do when using the `lag()` function.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in BigQuery in handling timestamps with the LAG function.

The timestamp type is lost during intermediate results. When the table is written it will be correctly written as a timestamp type in the resulting table, but any intermediate results interpret the type as a raw integer resulting in unexpected results.

You found the work-around: cast to a non-timestamp type before the LAG function.

This issue is logged in our internal issue tracker. Thank you for the bug report!

Comment: Hi Michael, is this in a public issue tracker anywhere? I'm still seeing this issue. We use this functionality a lot so it'd be great to know when we can stop using this work-around